# Jenkins User Acceptance code issue in Jenkins pipeline. How to implement multiple acceptance code in a single pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a pipeline in which after my deployment, I will perform functional test and on the basis of that I want to conclude that whether I want to proceed further or not. I used Jenkins "input" feature. I am getting the message to proceed further, but when I click OK the nothing happened, It is stucked there only. And also after first Approval I have send approval step below, after that only I have to release the result.
I am not able to understand how to achieve as I am new to this. The pipeline code is mentioned below:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

tools {
  // Install the Maven version configured as "M3" and add it to the path.
  maven "mvn"
  jdk "jdk8"
}

stages {
  stage('SCM Checkout') {
     steps {
        println "============= SCM Checkout =============="
     }
  }
  stage('Code Inspection'){
      steps {
        println "============== SonarQube Scanning ======================="
     }
  }
  stage('Build, Package & JUnit'){
      steps {
        println "============== Build, Package & JUnit ================"
     }
  }
  stage('Deploy'){
      steps {
        println "============== Deploy and Split Traffic==================" 
     }
  }
  stage('Functional & Performance Test'){
      steps {
        println "=========== Functional and Performance Test ==============="
     }
  }
  stage('A/B Testing'){
      input {
            message "Functional & Performance Test done. Should we continue?"
            ok "OK"
      }
      steps {
          println "=========== A/B Testing ==============="
     }
  }
  stage('Release'){
      input {
            message "A/B Testing done. Should we continue?"
            ok "OK"
      }
      steps {
          println "========= Final Release =================="
     }
  }
}}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? or who can I improve this code to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the input feature like this:

```
stage('Release'){
  steps {
      input message: "A/B Testing done. Should we continue?"
      println "========= Final Release =================="
 }
}
```

Make sure you also have the [Pipeline: Input Step Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Input+Step+Plugin) (a component of [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin)) installed and activated:

[image: Input Plug-In]

Comment: I tried this also but no luck. Still I am getting the option for proceed and abort, but when I click on them nothing happen. Is there any additional plugin required for this?

Comment: @AnkitSoni make sure you have the "Pipeline: Input Step" Plug-In installed and activated. 
I also tried your solution and it worked on my Jenkins. I could press "OK" and the job proceeded executions of the next steps. So both solutions - yours and mine are working for your needs.